# Get GET value from URL and save it in a file

Tags: php, formatting, lines

I want to get a GET value from the url and store it in a file. I just can't get it in the format which I want it.

Code:

```
<?php

    $emailaccount = $_GET['email'];
    $emailaccount .= '\n';

    file_put_contents($file, $emailaccount, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    echo 'done' . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

URL looks like:

```
www.website.com/index.php?email=account@gmail.com
```

My *.txt file *should* look like:

```
1account@gmail.com
2account@gmail.com
3account@gmail.com
```

But my file doesn't look like this, every value is on the same line, why?

Comment: Be careful with the @ sign in the URL.

Comment: What does your code do that you dont want it to?

Comment: It dont seperate the emails like it should.

Comment: My outcome is now: "email1@gmail.com\nemail2@gmail.com\nemail3@gmail.com"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `$emailaccount .= '\n';` to `$emailaccount .= "\r\n";` should do it.

EDIT

Here is why: \r\n is used for system compatibility and double quotes are needed in order for PHP to parse it as newline characters instead of a literal string.

Comment: Outcome is: "test1@gmail.com\r\ntest2@gmail.com\r\ntest3@gmail.com\r\n"

Comment: Have you copied it correctly? More specifically, did you put the double quotes?